# How do I make an resizable layout in SWT with standard sizes

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, layout, swt

I'm currently trying to make an application using SWT, I want to have something like in Finder where I can resize the different composites by dragging the edges. I also want to be able to set default widths of the left and right bar/composites. I first tried with a BoxLayout but have switched to an GroupLayout with little success.

Here's an picture of what I've got now[image: This is what it looks like now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple resizing can be done with a [`SashForm`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FSashForm.html). [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SashFormExample.htm) is a simple example showing how to use it. It will look similar to this:

[image]

As for the default width: It will be easier to help if you show some code.

Comment: Ahh thanks that's exactly what I were looking for. I could set the default widths in the SashForm by using the `setWeights` method